# Using iptables to measure nmap network bandwidth?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I'm working through some exercises and need to use `iptables` to monitor nmap traffic. The nmap command I have is:

```
nmap -oN nmap-scripts-all.txt --script=all 100.100.9.6
```

I've been reading about `iptables` and understand I can use it to block or filter incoming/outgoing traffic and also log dropped packets. What is the feature I should read about to log the network bandwidth of particular commands? I am familiar with other ways to do this such as `ftop` and `nload` but I would like to specifically solve this with `iptables` (if possible).

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is practically answerable - I would imagine you would use typically use wireshark (or tcpdump at a push) to create a dump file of traffic.  You can do logging with iptables [ for whatever it is you want to specify ] by creating a LOGGING Chain (see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/) but I'm not at all sure this is what you are wanting to do.    You may or may not want to tie this in with fail2ban to trigger on certain log events.

Comment: @davidgo That makes sense - makes me feel a bit better knowing that I'm not completely off base thinking this is a better task for other tools also. I'll make a pcap dump and work it from that angle, thank-you!

Comment: How do you plan to mark packets coming from a particular command (nmap) so you can process them differently with iptables?